# How can I get a mobile browser to leave one element alone

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I'm using a flexbox to show a group of sections all in a row when displayed on a big screen and then one on top of the other when the screen is made smaller.
This works on my computer and when I use the mobile emulator on chrome however when I use any browser on my mobile (Safari, Chrome, Firefox) it resizes it so two sections are next to each other hence making the words too small to read.

Now I tried adding this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
```

But that messed with the formatting of the rest of the page.
Is there anything similar but for just one element?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It should be working everywhere but you aren't showing any markup for us to help you.

Comment: Ok well if you need an example here you go.
Though it's nothing special.
http://codepen.io/bobbrom/pen/rygNeM

Answer (score 0):

You can use a media query to have the behavior only occur on certain resolutions so it effectively only runs on mobile. The below media query would run the contained style on all phones.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:766px) {
    .myClass {width:100vw;display:block;}
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of that but it kind of destroys the point of using flexbox doesn't it?

Comment: Sounds like in this case he wants flexbox to ignore this one instance. So why not?

Comment: @BobbyBromfield No, `flexbox` does not replace media queries.

Comment: @LGSon I know it doesn't replace it but if you have something that rearranges itself for a smaller screen than you add a media query. Then what's the point of the former thing?
I could have just used media queries in the first place. It'd look clunky and awkward but if I have a flexbox and media queries then it'll look like that anyway.

Comment: @BobbyBromfield You need a break point, and there is only two as of today, media query and `min-width`. You chose, and what is important is not whether it looks awkward or not, it is if it is readable, maintainable and performant

Comment: @LGSon Ok no offence but you're really not being helpful here.
I already know about media queries and `min-width`. 
What I was asking was if there was a way to get a mobile browser to reformat a certain element like the above piece of code does for an entire page.

Comment: @BobbyBromfield Non taken :) .... You ask for help with a code, a code none of us have seen, so tell me, how am I going to give any other answer than a general about the basic principles of how I understand your question? .... About `flexbox`, if you wonder if it has some magic property that acts similar to break points, it doesn't, it is simply a clever display value how one want its item to flow